# "imwrite" within CC Dynamic Android Library not found when beeing called from C-Code

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am using OpenCV 4.6.0 Android SDK which I downloaded from sourceforge and use it within my shared library/.so. This library is called from within my android app (aarch64). Building works fine using my **android.toolchain.cmake** :

```
...
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/username/Android/SDK/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/username/Android/SDK/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang++)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK /home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
...
```

And **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/opencv-4.6.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/abi-arm64-v8a)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/opencv-4.6.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opencv_highgui)
...
```

My `.h`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
   bool imwriteC(Bitmap *bitmap, const char *filename);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And `.cpp`

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "myheader.h"
...
bool imwriteWrapper(Bitmap *bitmap, const char *filename)
{
   Mat mat;
   // ...
   // bitmap to mat conversion here
   // ...
   return imwrite(filename, mat);
}
bool imwriteC(Bitmap *bitmap, const char *filename) {
   return imwriteWrapper(bitmap, filename);
}
```

I call my `imwriteC` from C-Code.
My error message looks like name-mangling

```
Unable to load library 'testlibrary':
"_ZN2cv7imwriteERKNSt6_ndk112basic_stringlcNS0_11char_traitslcEENS0_9allocatorlcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS0_6vectorliNS4_liEEEE" referenced by ... "/path/to/testlibrary.so"...
```

So it seems like OpenCVs `imwrite` can't be found due to name mangling issues(?).

Comment: Did you link with the appropriate opencv libraries? I don't see that in that short little snippet of CMakeLists.txt you show.

Comment: That's it! Sorry for the missing snipped, I was just using ```target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opencv_highgui)```; by changing this line to ```target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})``` it is working now. Thank you

Comment: No worries. The problem was that you linked with the `highgui` module, but [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) is now in `imgcodecs` module. Using `${OpenCV_LIBS}` ends up linking with all the modules, so it works. | You might be using some obsolete tutorials or whatnot, given that you linked with `highgui` -- `imwrite` used to be in that library, but that was back in version 2.4.x. Lot of things have changed since then, better cross-reference things with current docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about mangling, you just didn't link with all the OpenCV libraries that you need.

You're using OpenCV version 4.6.0. I see that you're calling [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce), and you're linking with the `highgui` module. Well, once upon a time (in 2.4.x) that would have worked, but IIRC since 3.x (and definitely in 4.x) this function resides in `imgcodecs` module. So you should change that `target_link_libraries` statement to something like

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE opencv_imgcodecs)
```

Furthermore, since you're using a `Mat` there, you might need the `core` module. Often you can figure out the name of the module from the documentation (best look at the URL -- for `imwrite` there's `group__imgcodecs.html` in the middle, and the module name is after the two underscores).

---

Of course, as you found out, since you `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`, you can also take the shortcut and link with `${OpenCV_LIBS}`, which ends up trying all the OpenCV modules. I guess that's good enough choice, although personally I prefer to explicitly specify exactly what I need and no more.